# Android Radio Player m3u8 error

Tags: java, android, m3u8, internet-radio

```
04-24 21:51:06.092: I/global(406): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
04-24 21:51:06.296: D/PlsParser(406): Playlist Url = http:/ / 85 dot 204 dot 233 dot  122/radio-01/stream-high-02/playlist.m3u8?wowzasessionid=1094958256
04-24 21:51:06.296: I/System.out(406): Playlist: Selected url - http:/ / 85 dot 204 dot 233 dot  122/radio-01/stream-high-02/playlist.m3u8?wowzasessionid=1094958256
04-24 21:51:06.616: E/MediaPlayer(406): error (1, -2147483648)
04-24 21:51:06.622: E/MediaPlayer(406): Error (1,-2147483648)
04-24 21:51:06.622: I/System.out(406): RadioService: stop
04-24 21:51:06.632: E/MediaPlayer(406): stop called in state 0
04-24 21:51:06.632: E/MediaPlayer(406): error (-38, 0)
04-24 21:51:06.652: V/ERROR(406): MEDIA ERROR UNKNOWN -2147483648
04-24 21:51:06.672: E/MediaPlayer(406): stop called in state 1
04-24 21:51:06.672: E/MediaPlayer(406): error (-38, 0)
04-24 21:51:06.692: D/PlsParser(406): Setting next stream from playlist: 0
04-24 21:51:06.692: D/PlsParser(406): URL = http:/ / 85 dot 204 dot 233 dot  122/radio-01/stream-high-02/playlist.m3u8?wowzasessionid=1094958256
04-24 21:51:06.822: I/global(406): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
04-24 21:51:07.002: D/PlsParser(406): Playlist Url = http:/ / 85 dot 204 dot 233 dot  122:1935/radio-01/_definst_/stream-high-02/key.m3u8key?wowzasessionid=1094958256"
04-24 21:51:07.002: W/dalvikvm(406): threadid=18: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-24 21:51:07.002: E/AndroidRuntime(406): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-21
04-24 21:51:07.002: E/AndroidRuntime(406): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
04-24 21:51:07.002: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
04-24 21:51:07.002: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
04-24 21:51:07.002: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at com.my.radio.RadioService$3.run(RadioService.java:294)
04-24 21:51:07.002: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
04-24 21:51:07.432: D/webviewglue(406): nativeDestroy view: 0x3037c0
04-24 21:51:07.442: D/webviewglue(406): nativeDestroy view: 0x303450
04-24 21:51:08.022: D/dalvikvm(406): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5811 objects / 296264 bytes in 501ms
04-24 21:51:08.412: E/ActivityThread(406): Activity com.my.radio.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.my.radio.BaseActivity$1@45fd26a8 that was originally bound here
04-24 21:51:08.412: E/ActivityThread(406): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.my.radio.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.my.radio.BaseActivity$1@45fd26a8 that was originally bound here
04-24 21:51:08.412: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(ActivityThread.java:1121)
04-24 21:51:08.412: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.getServiceDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:1016)
04-24 21:51:08.412: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:863)
04-24 21:51:08.412: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:347)
04-24 21:51:08.412: E/ActivityThread(406):  at com.my.radio.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:39)
04-24 21:51:08.412: E/ActivityThread(406):  at com.my.radio.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:79)
04-24 21:51:08.412: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-24 21:51:08.412: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-24 21:51:08.412: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-24 21:51:08.412: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-24 21:51:08.412: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-24 21:51:08.412: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 21:51:08.412: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-24 21:51:08.412: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-24 21:51:08.412: E/ActivityThread(406):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 21:51:08.412: E/ActivityThread(406):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-24 21:51:08.412: E/ActivityThread(406):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-24 21:51:08.412: E/ActivityThread(406):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-24 21:51:08.412: E/ActivityThread(406):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 21:51:08.463: E/ActivityThread(406): Activity com.my.radio.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.my.radio.MainActivity$2@45fd30d8 that was originally bound here
04-24 21:51:08.463: E/ActivityThread(406): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.my.radio.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.my.radio.MainActivity$2@45fd30d8 that was originally bound here
04-24 21:51:08.463: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(ActivityThread.java:1121)
04-24 21:51:08.463: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.getServiceDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:1016)
04-24 21:51:08.463: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:863)
04-24 21:51:08.463: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:347)
04-24 21:51:08.463: E/ActivityThread(406):  at com.my.radio.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:85)
04-24 21:51:08.463: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-24 21:51:08.463: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-24 21:51:08.463: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-24 21:51:08.463: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-24 21:51:08.463: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-24 21:51:08.463: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 21:51:08.463: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-24 21:51:08.463: E/ActivityThread(406):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-24 21:51:08.463: E/ActivityThread(406):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 21:51:08.463: E/ActivityThread(406):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-24 21:51:08.463: E/ActivityThread(406):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-24 21:51:08.463: E/ActivityThread(406):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-24 21:51:08.463: E/ActivityThread(406):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 21:51:09.452: I/Process(406): Sending signal. PID: 406 SIG: 9
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! please post some code (along with this error message) and a question we can answer.

Answer (score 2):

welcome to Stackoverflow.com :), i think you have an IndexOutofBounds Exception:  `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1`

this is an example of how i play an `.M3U8` using a `VideoView`:

```
    private VideoView myvideoview;
    private String urlStream;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
       String streamV = "http://media.jorgesys.com/reforma.m3u8";
       new playM3U8().execute(streamV); 
       myvideoview = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);                    

       myvideoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                myvideoview.start();                                
            }
        });

       myvideoview.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                Log.i("Exception", "url: " + url);
                return false;
            }
        });

   }
```

This class is an AyncTask to play the M3U8:

```
    class playM3U8 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        private Exception exception;        

        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            urlStream = urls[0];
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        myvideoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlStream));                  
                    }
                }); 
            return null; 
        } 

        protected void onPostExecute(String feed) {
            Log.i("*** Streaming M3U8", "url: " + urlStream );
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Just curious: why do you store the possible `Exception`?

Comment: I have edited my answer, you can avoid this listener: "myvideoview.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {" was useful for me to show me a message for any exception :)